# On the existence of a certain sequence of positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I wish to find a sequence of strictly positive real numbers $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$, such that
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k} < \infty
$$
and such that for all $m, n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ with $m \leq \frac{n}{2}$ the following relation holds
$$
\frac{\ln(n - m) \times \ln(m)}{\ln(n)} \leq a_m
$$
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Note that $$\frac{\log\left(x-m\right)\log\left(m\right)}{\log\left(x\right)}$$ is an increasing function so, with your limitation, the best admissible choice of $n$ is $n=2m.$
Then $$a_{m}=\frac{\log\left(m\right)^{2}}{\log\left(2\right)+\log\left(m\right)}$$ but $$\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{a_{k}}{k}=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\log\left(k\right)^{2}}{k\left(\log\left(2\right)+\log\left(k\right)\right)}>\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{1}{k\left(\log\left(2\right)+\log\left(k\right)\right)}=\infty.$$

Comment: How do you know that last series diverges?

Comment: @JackM You can prove it a lot of way, for example by comparison test.

Comment: Thank you very much. And what if you replace $\ln(x)$ everywhere in the question by $x^{-c}$ for some $c > 0$?

Comment: Do you mean the condition $$\frac{\left(n^{-c}-m\right)m}{n^{-c}}\leq a_{m}?$$

Comment: No, I mean $$\frac{(n - m)^{-c} \times m^{-c}}{n^{-c}} = \left(\frac{(n - m)m}{n}\right)^{-c} \leq a_m$$

Comment: @EvanAad in this case it works. Take $n=2m$ and see the result.