# On the existence of a certain sequence of positive numbers II

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

I wish to find a sequence of strictly positive real numbers $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$, such that
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k} < \infty
$$
and such that for all $m, n \in \{1, 2, \dots\}$ with $m \leq \frac{n}{2}$ the following relation holds for any fixed $0 < c < 1$.
$$
E_{m, n} \leq a_m
$$
where
$$
E_{m, n} := \frac{\exp(-(n - m)^c) \times \exp(-m^c)}{\exp(-n^c)}
$$

Any help will be appreciated.

---

***An attempt at a solution***

It may be helpful to note that
$$
E_{m, n} = \exp\left(-n^c\left[\left(1 - \frac{m}{n}\right)^c + \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^c - 1\right]\right)
$$
and therefore on the one hand for all $m$
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_{m, n} = \exp(-m^c)
$$
while on the other hand for any $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$ we have
$$
E_{\varepsilon n, n} = \exp\left(-\delta_\varepsilon n^c\right)
$$
where
$$
\delta_\varepsilon = (1-\varepsilon)^c + \varepsilon^c - 1
$$
is a positive constant.

---

***A related post***

A couple days ago [I asked a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207169/on-the-existence-of-a-certain-sequence-of-positive-numbers) but with logarithms instead of exponents. That question was solved by [Marco Cantarini](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/186170/marco-cantarini).

Comment: $E_{m,n}$ seems (but I have not properly checked it) to be maximal at the minimum value $n=2m$. There $E_{m,n} = e^{-(2 - 2^c) m^c}$. This expression for $a_m$ leads to convergence for the series.

Comment: @Winther: I think $E_{m, n}$ is maximal at $n = m$, where $E_{m, n} = 1$.

Comment: But you have $2m \leq n$ as a condition...

Comment: @Winther: You're right. Thank you! Don't you want to write the answer to get the credit?